# Unable to login to Windows XP after changing language from Arabic to English

Tags: windows-xp, login, language, regional-settings

Please help me out. after changing the regional settings from Arabic to English in Windows XP. I am not able to login to the computer as it accepts only the English. I didn't add the Arabic keyboard to the regional language settings. Is there any way to get through this. Its very urgent.

Comment: Can you jump in to safe mode? Either to reset the user password, add the required keyboard or maybe perform a system restore.

Comment: no i cannot jump into safe mode option.at the login screen the password was earlier in arabic. now it doesnt shift to arabic. it is fixed in english.how do i do a system restore from this point and if i do a system restore, do i loose my files

Answer (score 0):

Download this ISO file, burn it to CD as an Image (not data) Boot from it and reset the password to a blank one.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/pcloginnow/

.

Comment: Thanks a ton for the solution and thanks to you too mepher

Comment: You can mark my answer as the solution, you are welcome sumair.